# make an LED blink with PT100 in arduino

Tags: arduino, pt100

i want to connect PT100 with arduino and Turn it on with a botton and LED on until 250 Celsius and then wit for 5 seconds if within 5 seconds  the temperature getting down turn LED on again for half second.   but after 5  seconds turn both of.

i request you please help me .

Comment: Please, ask specific question. What exactly is your problem with? Do you expect someone to build a prototype, write the entire code and present it here?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to some tutorials online. Internet is full of Arduino projects.

For example https://bestengineeringprojects.com/measuring-temperature-using-pt100-and-arduino/

Don't post questions here unless you have one specific question. Request for designing the whole project is not a question.

Comment: thanks for your reply.    i need only the basic code,   and not the design

Comment: even the basic code is designed.